# Как сверстать два блока на всю высоту страницы?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Есть данная структура страниц, как сделать так, чтоб на высоких экранах блок `.content` тянулся до `footer`.
Пример можно посмотреть [тут](http://codepen.io/Benny214/pen/yeWLLw)

```
<div id="wrapContent" class="wrapContent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <header>
      </header>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="content" class="content clearfix">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="col-xs-8 leftBlock">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 rightBlock">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>



    html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.wrapContent {
  overflow: visible !important;
  height: auto !important;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -71px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  background: #323742;
}

.container {
  width: 1170px !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  overflow: visible;
  height: 189px;
  background: #222;
}

.content {
  min-height: 516px;
}

.flex-container {
  min-height: 516px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: -15px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.leftBlock {
  background: #fff;
}

.rightBlock {
  background: #ccc;
}

footer {
  background: #222;
  height: 71px;
}
```

Comment: если выставить высоту от 1000px, то все разваливается http://i.imgur.com/YbY5DI1.png

Answer (score 2):

Про FlexBox: на [русском](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/) и [английском](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Поддержка FlexBox [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

[image: Поддержка FlexBox]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: #222;
}
.content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
      -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
          flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.content .left {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
      -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
          flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.content .right {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 300px;
      -ms-flex: 0 1 300px;
          flex: 0 1 300px;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 75px;
  background-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="content">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

В Блок .flex-container добавьте margin-left: -15px;

Comment: поправил, но от этого к сожалению, лучше не станет

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, за ответы. Мои проблемы решил простой скрипт

```js
 function rightBlockHeight() {
    var height = $( window ).height() - $( '#footer' ).height() - $( "#header" ).height();
    $( '#content' ).css( 'min-height', height );
    $( '.rightBlock' ).css( 'min-height', height );
  }
  $( document ).ready( function() {
    rightBlockHeight();
  } );
  $( window ).resize( function() {
    rightBlockHeight();
  } );
```